# mongodb aggregate documents by dates nearest to specific hour/minute in day

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents in my mongodb, this documents have `event` field - this fild type is `date`. The year, month , day, does not matter, means only the time during day. I want the cron script,every day, to aggregate from mongodb the documents with the `event` (date typed) field to be in nearest 10 minutes (to the script calling date). How to implement it in right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.mytable.find(
    {
        "event": {
            $gt: new Date(new Date().getTime() - (10 * 60 * 1000))
        }
    })
```

This query will find all documents that have an `"event"` property with a value within the past 10 minutes.  `new Date()` without arguments returns a `Date` representing "right now".  We pull the numeric epoch time in milliseconds from that and subtract 10 minutes.  More specifically, we subtract (10 minutes * 60 seconds per minute * 1000 milliseconds per second), so that we convert to the correct units.  We then use that value to construct another `new Date(...)`, and this is the one that goes into the `$gt` (greater-than) filtering condition.

You mentioned a need for "aggregation".  If so, then this same query can also be used within any [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) that you need.

Comment: Could you please help on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61131299/mongodb-datetostring-format-to-show-time-by-15min-interval