# mongoDB: $dateToString format to show time by 15min interval

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a example here, 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/fqxBy6NAZXL

As you will see final result has "dateHour" and "minuteBucket" fields. 
I am dividing time by 15.0 minutes so "minuteBucket" value will always be one of 0, 1, 2, 3

"dateHour" is not showing minutes right now.

Expected :

**I need to remove "minuteBucket" field but still divide time by 15 minutes for this aggregation and show "dateHour" with HH:MM where it always round up by 15 minutes.** 
example it should look like in this format based on its time.

```
"2020-03-19T18:00:00", "2020-03-19T18:15:00","2020-03-19T18:30:00","2020-03-19T18:45:00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) to parse `dateHour` and then add `_id.minutebucket` multiplied by `900000` (15 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 miliseconds):

```
{
    dateHour: {
        $let: {
            vars: { parsedDate: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$_id.dateHour", format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H" } } },
            in: { $toString: [ { $add: [ "$$parsedDate", { $multiply: [ "$_id.minuteBucket", 900000 ] } ] } ] }
        }
    }
}
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uKKpeRJY57r)

Comment: let me point out, you saved my many hours 2 days in a row now. thanks a lot. I should have your email address just in case if I stuck bad in mognodb queries lol...Thanks

Comment: btw, i also needed to remove minuteBucket from the projected fields. if I remove it now it breaks the query. could you pls help with that?

Comment: @newdeveloper remove it from the last stage only

Comment: it worked. i was doing this minuteBucket: 0, and it was giving error thanks

Comment: I am using this in shell script but it gives me error not sure whats missing in sytax -- ZONE_AGGREGATE_COMMAND+='  dateHour: {$let: {vars: {parsedDate: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$_id.dateHour",format: "%Y-%m-%dT%H"}}},in: {$toString: [{$add: ["$$parsedDate",{$multiply: ["$_id.minuteBucket",900000]}]}]}}},'

Comment: error is :  E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell eval):15:0